# How to remove the green rectangle while scanning QR codes using the ZBar SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, qr-code, zbar-sdk

```
- (IBAction)scanProduct:(id)sender
{   
   // for scanning product
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;    
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;    
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                                   to: 0];    
    [self presentModalViewController: readerqr
                                        animated: YES];  
}
```

when clicks on button readerqr appears with green rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation for ZBarReaderViewController](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarReaderViewController.html), it looks like setting `tracksSymbols` to `NO` might do the trick.